# Different types of MongoDB nodes

Tags: mongodb

I am building a monitoring plugin designed to detect--among other things--when any given Mongo node is down. These are the types of nodes I am looking for: `mongo-s`, `mongo-d` `configsvr`, replica set, and the individual shards that make up the replica set--a primary, secondaries, and arbiters. I am gathering the list of nodes from the `getShardMap` command, and querying each node individually to find out which type it is. Are there any other types of nodes I might need to be aware of? And, if so, where can I find them listed within Mongo commands?

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got the different "types" of nodes covered, but you might also want to monitor the current "state" of each node in each replica set (in addition to being PRIMARY or SECONDARY, a node can also be in a RECOVERY state, or in a ROLLBACK state, etc.).  You can query for the state using the replSetGetStatus command.  The different states are listed here:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Set+Commands#ReplicaSetCommands-state